# Error in terminal while running a code

Tags: gnome-terminal, sublime-text

I installed Ubuntu yesterday, so I don't know what many of the commands mean. I am just learning as they come.
I installed Sublime Text 3 editor and tried to compile and run a program using a tutorial based on Ubuntu 16.04.
The compilation was successful, but it shows some sort of error like this and the opened running terminal doesn't do anything.

[image: IMAGE 1]

So what I did was to change the build system: in line 12 I removed '-e' and added '--':

[image: IMAGE 2]

[image: IMAGE 3]

Now the error is not shown in the compile status, but the terminal is showing another error.

[image: IMAGE 4]

I think I need to make some additional changes to the Build System.

Here's the code I used for Build System:

```
{
 "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
 "variants":
 [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell": true,
        "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c 
        \"${file_path}/${file_base_name};echo;echo;  echo Press ENTER 
        to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sublime Text 3 build systems `cmd` has a different syntax: you should write each argument of command in different quotes, like this:

```
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal", "-e", "'bash -e ...'"]
```

It's easier to use `shell_cmd`.

```
"shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'Your command here'"
```

For example, this will execute your compiled program and wait for any key to be pressed:

```
"shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal -- bash -c '${file_path}/${file_base_name}; read -sn 1'"
```

Comment: Thanks  :) it actually helped...now my terminal automatically opens with the code compiled and without error...but I still have to type `./a.out` to run the program...is there a way to skip that too?

Comment: It means that you compile your file manually with `g++ ${file_name}`. And default output filename for g++ is `a.out`. You can replace your run command with `${file_path}/a.out`, or compile file with default build system